# Micrsoft Graph api to search folders in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My application was using Microsoft Graph to search OneDrive, and it was working fine till last month.

It's basically this call for "search my onedrive":

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q=%27finance%27)?select=name,id,webUrl)

and you can run it in the online Microsoft Graph explorer as well:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

The problem is now it's not returning any folders, it just returns files. I've noticed that if I do a search online on OneDrive, it gives the same result by default with "All files" selected. When I change the search bar dropdown to "My Files", it works and gives me both folders and files as before.

[image]

Any ideas on how to switch from "All files" to "My Files" in the API call? Hopefully it's something simple by adding an option to the query parameter.